# OpsHub TFS to VSTS migration - Object reference not set to an object exception

Tags: tfs, migration, azure-devops, opshub

Getting error "Object Reference not set to an instance of object". on the screen 'Migration Project(s)'. Select Team Project(s) does not fill in projects for migration. I am overall TFS administrator and have full access. Migration we are doing is from TFS 2010 to VSTS. we are using free version. Please let me know what needs to be done to fix the issue.

1) Checked whether all components needed are installed and they are installed (TFS Object Model 2012 and Dot Net framework 4.0)

2) Cleared cache folders under program files

Comment: Do you use the latest version of OVSMU?

Answer (score 0):

Check the solution in this case: [OpsHub: ERROR Object reference not set to an instance of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216130/opshub-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object)

> The Migration Utility expects "Project Collection Service Accounts" to
>   be present in the VSO account Groups which is created by default when
>   you create your VSO account, but due to some unknown issue some
>   accounts created between the specific date this group was created as
>   "Team Foundation Service Accounts" as in your case, so the migration
>   utility was not able to find the desired group which resulted in the
>   issue you are facing, you can continue the migration by creating a VSO
>   group "Project Collection Service Accounts", add the user in this
>   group which was used for authentication of VSO account for migration
>   utility and make sure the newly created VSO group is a member of "Team
>   Foundation Administrators"