# OpsHub TFS to VSTS migration - Object reference not set to an object exception error message

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

Getting error "Object Reference not set to an instance of object". on the screen 'Migration Project(s)'. Select Team Project(s) does not fill in projects for migration. I am overall TFS administrator and have full access. Migration we are doing is from TFS 2010 to VSTS. we are using free version. Please let me know what needs to be done to fix the issue.

Checked whether all components needed are installed and they are installed (TFS Object Model 2012 and Dot Net framework 4.0)

Carried out the Proxy settings too.

Advised to post this here.

Originally tried to post on [OpsHub TFS to VSTS migration - Object reference not set to an object exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49769513/opshub-tfs-to-vsts-migration-object-reference-not-set-to-an-object-exception/49771191#49771191) but not allowed.

The solution provided there did not work. I am a Project Collection Administrator on the VSTS side and an Admin on the TFS side.

The version is V2.8.1.000

```
2018-04-04 11:32:07,636 [1] ERROR Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 at TFSMigrationUI.ViewModel.ProjectSelectionViewModel.loadProjectWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) in F:\checkout\OIM-OAM\OIM-OAM\TFSMigration\TFSMigrationUI\ViewModel\ProjectSelectionViewModel.cs:line 385
 at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnRunWorkerCompleted(RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
 at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
 at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

Comment: Is there detail log? What's the result if you try it on a different machine?

Comment: Updated above to include the error message. I do not have access to another computer (with the correct set of administrative rights) on this network to get access to the TFS.

Comment: Are others have the same issue with the same TFS?

Comment: Only have users actively using the TFS - it is working for them. I can use the TFS through VS on the computer that has the OpsHub software installed.

Comment: What's the result if you try it with different account (others' account) on that machine?

Comment: Will try and let you know.

Comment: What's the result now?